# Can I create a transparent command window in Windows

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Windows 7: Transparent command window?](https://superuser.com/questions/40385/windows-7-transparent-command-window)
>   [Transparent Command Prompt in Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/3365/transparent-command-prompt-in-vista)

In Ubuntu [I can create a totally transparent terminal on my desktop](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-create-a-transparent-terminal-in-ubuntu-desktop.html)

Is there anyway I can achieve this in Windows??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) looks like it might do the trick, if you're looking for just a transparent console in particular.

> Console is a Windows console window enhancement. Console features include: multiple tabs, text editor-like text selection, different background types, alpha and color-key transparency, configurable font, different window styles

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[PowerMenu](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/)** - it does transparency and a few other things.

[image]