# Using a map screenshot as a "tracing paper" for a city-building video game?

Tags: layers

I'm trying to recreate real cities in a video game in a 1:1 scale and it's quite tedious to get every proportion right (let's say it's close to impossible).

So I've come up with an idea but I really don't know how to make it happen. I think this is the right SE to ask (if I'm mistaken I will delete my question).

Let's say I have this google map screenshot :
[image]

And this is my game in windowed mode :
[image]

Is there any way to render the google map screenshot as a low opacity window, while letting me have full control of my windowed mode game with constant input ? So I could use it as a tracing paper and easily reproduce real life dimensions

Comment: um... in nearly any piece of design software this is possible. But I get the feeling you're talking about inside your game which is probably off-topic here. Not to mention you don't say what game it is. I'm going to put this on hold until you clarify using the [edit] button.

Comment: not inside the game, but above the game yes. I mean the tracing paper would be outside the game of course, but visually above it. Like using layers in photoshop, but between applications.

Comment: ah I see. I think SuperUser will be better for this than as it has nothing to do with Design. I'll migrate it over or attempt to (no idea if they'll accept).

Comment: Part of this question I believe is a duplicate of [Make window always on top?](http://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top). The other part has to do with lowering the transparency of the window itself might be a duplicate of [Transparent Command Prompt in Vista?](http://superuser.com/questions/3365/transparent-command-prompt-in-vista) or [Windows 7: Transparent command window?](http://superuser.com/questions/40385/windows-7-transparent-command-window)

Comment: Just a quick idea (that's why posted as comment): Set the transparency of your _game_ to 60% or something like that (possible with e.g. [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en)). Then you can put it _in front of you browser_ which displays the map.

Comment: yes I didn't think of doing it that way but it makes sense. I'll have to see if it's possible, I didn't know this software

Comment: 1:1 scale = actual size?

Comment: FYI, if you are literally using maps, I'd suggest you source your game from open source maps such as openstreetmap rather than Google to avoid copyright infringement issues.

Comment: yes, ingame the cities are rendered in their actual size, relatively speaking. By the way it's not my game, I'm just using it, it's called Cities Skylines. I don't think Google would mind a simple user like me using their maps for hobby purposes !

Comment: by the way it works perfectly with Dexpot. @mpy if you want to reformulate as an anwser ! thanks

Comment: (+1) This is a pretty helpful post for anyone playing Cities: Skylines :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use e.g. [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en), a virtual desktop manager for Windows which is "free for private use only" to render any program window translucent by right clicking on the title bar (or on the task bar entry):

[image]

In my example it's MS Paint, in your case it's your game's map editor. Then you can place this program *in front* of any other program and use it just like a real tracing paper:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cities Skyline height map generator: http://www.skylinescity.com/2015/03/height-map-creation-tool-for-creating-real-world-location-maps

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged (links might die!), please give a summary (_not_ copy&paste) of the linked page and give the link as reference only.