# Simple Way To Display Script Output On Windows Desktop? (Like GeekTool on OSX)

Tags: windows, desktop, script, geektool

I'd like to display the output of some command-line scripts on my Windows desktop.  I believe Rainmeter and Samurize can do this, but I find Rainmeter kind of baffling and frankly it's just overkill for my needs anyway.  And Samurize looks like a dead project at this point.

For an example of exactly what I want, look at GeekTool for OSX: http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/

For each desktop item, Geektool lets you choose colors, the script command whose output you want to display, how often to refresh it, and you can also choose colors and transparency.  That's basically it and that's all I want.

Is there a Windows equivalent?  I don't need any fancy system monitoring capability built into the app itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samurize doesn't look to me like a dead project, just slow in development.
Perhaps you were looking at the [old site](http://www.samurize.com/), rather than the [new site](http://forums.samurize.us/index.php?app=portal).

Version 1.64.3 Final was posted on September 2009.
The latest software, PluginPak 1.09, was posted on July 2010.

For info about using Samurize, see this article:
[Geek to Live: Incorporate text files onto your desktop](http://lifehacker.com/213280/geek-to-live--incorporate-text-files-onto-your-desktop)

Comment: The 'new' website seems dead to me, at least currently.

Comment: @Rabarberski: Domain name seems to have elapsed. Unless it comes back, one would need to google for PluginPak 1.09.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a transparant console: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TransparentCommandPromptInWindows.aspx

   Alternatives: [Transparent Command Prompt in Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/3365/transparent-command-prompt-in-vista)
2. Keep the window from going active or in front of your windows by writing a simple script:
   http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml
3. Hide the title border:
   http://my.opera.com/AyushJ/blog/winchanger

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, couldn't you just use terminal, and cat to display text file, if you are using constantly updated logs then perhaps tail?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That would work from a technical perspective.  

However, I am thinking of something unobtrusive that could display some text on the desktop itself (ie, it would be a transparent window that floats below all other windows)

Sort of like a desktop widget, basically.  In fact, maybe one of the existing widgets out there does something like this.

Answer (score 0):

[BgInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx) by Sysinternal is an excellent tool for Windows to write system info on the desktop. You could configure it to display your script output

Comment: That looks like a neat utility (love Sysinternals!)  However I'm looking to display some script output and not just system info.  Thanks for the reply, though, because I think Bginfo will come in handy at some point.